# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ value: string; }'

Tags: typescript

I'am learning typescript and i don't know how to solve this.

My goal is to find a key: string in some random text and replace it with the value: string.

```
export class Smiley {
    private smiley: {[key: string]: {value: string}} = {
        ':-)': '°>sm_00...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°',
        ':-(': '°>sm_03...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°',
        ':-|': '°>sm_13...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°',
        ':-D': '°>sm_10...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°',
        ':-O': '°>sm_06...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°',
    };
    tbsmiley(str: string): string {
        const obj = this.smiley;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
            const ind = str.indexOf(key);
            if ( ind >= 0 ) {
                str = str.substring(0, ind) + obj[key] + str.substr(ind + key.length);
                return str;
            }
        });
        return str;
    }
}
```

Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ value: string; }'.
The expected type comes from this index signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

You either need this...

```
private smiley: {[key: string]: string } = { // <--- changed type
  ':-)': '°>sm_00...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°',
  ':-(': '°>sm_03...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°',
};
```

... or you need this.

```
private smiley: {[key: string]: { value: string } } = { 
  ':-)': { value: '°>sm_00...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°' }, // <-- changed values
  ':-(': { value: '°>sm_03...b.pw_18.ph_18.gif<°' }, // <-- changed values
};
```

Note that an [index type's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) value does not need the `value` keyword.

Here are two more examples. The `ObjectValues` type is what you did; the `StringValues` type might be what you want.

```
type ObjectValues = {
    [key: string]: { value: string }
}

const objectValues: ObjectValues = {
  'someKey1': { value: 'someValue1' },
  'someKey2': { value: 'someValue2' }
}

type StringValues = {
    [key: string]: string;
}

const stringValues: ObjectValues = {
  'someKey1': 'someValue1',
  'someKey2': 'someValue2',
}
```

Here is your example [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GUC2BLJYATzgG8BYAKDhrjCjwDcUZg419CiAuMgbQDWxXmhgMAdgHMAuiLF4pcAL5wAvGTgB6TXAA8AWkOIAFiinAAJnBhEwwKrUdwA5N30BKVy4ANAPg4A+gAMQQB04QBGoWAA7gEAjAAc0cYJyZJ4AGa63s4ANA5ONK76ABRezn6BQQDM4aFRsWkpzRnZuQXURS5uAD4VVTgJdZHRcUktE205+YVFJQAiA-5D8WGjTRNgqVNZM53dPfoA8svVAGz1jePJ2617HXPKANxPMBEcBMSlolByEpJ3P8FJIyE9HAgIOJRHAIBEAFZqazGPBoUKfLivLpFY4I4AIGChIRENClOHw9yhTLQACiKAQxlKpWJ7jUvjB2MOiChMIUVnUv1CfNAx0yzOI7ixXNoWTgpTgfLgvnUQTgrIonOlNF+SMFaAArh95FJSkE8grxBZWQBqWEIwTEaRwW16w2-UqK23E0KEKQwYyS8FaqDAGD6qDidhiKVapRUINFbRwAAKIcYwHE8H9bEhODAXygcGAUCg0BcADkIPAUEgkNyLGwwCxjJgQ2GI3AUHBmEh9cBQs4E05-aWYnBxMAxzSS9BypX4NT9ZbnIHNbQlKuh23w5HfjGaHHKEogA) and [also here in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GUC2BLJYATzgG8BYAKDhrjCjwDcUZg419CiAuMgbQDWxXmhgMAdgHMAur1JxmSAK7ARYvFLgBfbXAC8ZOFVom4Acm4BaAJQXDilbzMAGgHwcA+gAYvAOn8ARr5gAO4eAIwAHMEAFhHRkngAZgA8zmbaADRwAPQ5cCmWlogxKFLAACYKKMrAaMamNBaWABR28g6q5m6eXgDM-r5BofGxo4mp6Vm5+YXFCKXlVZ311LRaANwNNNtwMAEcBMQtolBqEpLW5xqSZLsmCBDionAQAQBW+nsxeGi+h1wtmtGgB5D7ABAwXxCIhoFpvd7WXxJaAAURQCxaLRh1n0rjuwMatEez3gGiqBlOvnJoBBSWxxGsQKJpmScBacHJcFcBi8cFxFEJLJMpy+VLQSgO6ikLS82XJuIA1K8PoJiNI4MrxZLTi0ucqYb5CFIYDEmfdhTQoMAYEooOJ2GJmZbtFQLY08nAAArWxjAcTwU1sR44MBHKBwYBQKDQcwAOQg8BqSEQEAqbDALBimGttvtcBQ1VqvjM7tMppjITg4mAVdR0egbQT8BRSnEFTM5qF6y7Zdzdodp2dNC0VC0QA) with the two approaches.